# Group Homology of a Sylow $p$-Subgroup

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, sylow-theory, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

I am trying to understand the proof of the following proposition:

**Proposition** *Let $G$ be a finite group and let $P$ be a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then for all $n$ there is an isomorphism*
$$
H_n(G;\mathbb{F}_p) \cong H_n(P;\mathbb{F}_p)_Q,
$$
*where $G$ acts trivially on $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $Q := G/P$.*

**Proof**: The associated Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence takes the form
$$
E_{s,t}^2 \cong H_s(Q;H_t(P;\mathbb{F}_p)) \implies H_n(G;\mathbb{F}_p),
$$
where $s+t=n$. The groups $H_t(P;\mathbb{F}_p)$ are $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector spaces. We know that $\gcd(|Q|,p)=1$, where $|Q|$ denotes $\text{ord}(Q)$, and hence $|Q|$ is invertible in $H_t(P;\mathbb{F}_p)$. Therefore, the spectral sequence is concentrated on the line $s=0$ and we get
\begin{align*}
H_s(Q;H_t(P;\mathbb{F}_p)) \cong 
\begin{cases}
0 &  s > 0, \newline
H_t(P;\mathbb{F}_p)_Q & s=0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
All extension problems are trivial and the result follows.

**Questions**

1. I'm not sure I understand how $|Q|$ is invertible in $H_t(P;\mathbb{F}_p)$. An element $\alpha \in H_t(P;\mathbb{F}_p)$ is represented by $x \otimes z$, where $x$ is an element of some projective resolution $F$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}P$ and $z \in \mathbb{F}_p$. Can we simply say that $|Q| \cdot (x \otimes z) = x \otimes |Q|z$ and hence $|Q|z$ has an inverse, since $\gcd(|Q|,p)=1$? Is there a canonical multiplicative structure on $H_t(P;\mathbb{F}_p)$?
2. I do not understand how it follows from part (1.) that $E^2_{s,t} \cong 0$ if $s > 0$.

Any help is welcome, cheers!

Comment: H_t(P, F_p) is an abelian group of exponent p. Multiplication by a number coprime to p is therefore an automorphism. That is what it means for |Q| to be invertible there.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for the help! Then I think 2. follows from the fact that we can write the multiplication with $|Q|$ as the composite $i_* \circ \text{tr}$, i.e. of the transfer map and the inclusion. In particular this factors through $H_i(\{1\};\mathbb{F}_p)$, which is trivial for $i \geq 1$.

Comment: Exactly ${}{}{}$